Power Automate - Taking an attachment from one email and adding it to another gives a corrupted attachment
I have a scenario when I need to monitor an inbox for new emails, and then based on a set of rules forward the email and certain attachments to a new inbox.
There are scenarios where I need to only send certain attachments and not all of them.
I thought I got this to work, but my attachments in the new email are corrupt.

The trigger of the flow is 'When a new email arrives (V3)'
I then loop through the attachments and use Get Attachment (V2) to get more info
Then I add the attachment to an array as an object with "name" and "contentBytes" properties



And in the Send Email node I am adding this array into the attachments area


Trying to open the attachments from the new email does not work. They are corrupt.
I think I need to do something with the content bytes, but I'm not sure what.
I've tried base64 encoding it and adding quotations but it doesn't work.
Is it possible to attach files from an email trigger to a new email?
